# angular pattern Validator to stop called onblur

Tags: angular

I am using Validator in angular 5.(blur)="update(false)" get called when validation is incorrect. How can I stop onblur to get called if input value in invalid.

```
  <input required pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$"
         id="url" (blur)="update(false)" type="text" class="form-control" name="url"
         [(ngModel)]="urls" #url="ngModel">
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.required && url.touched">
    URL is required
  </span>
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.pattern && url.touched">
    URL is Invalid
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input required pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$"
         id="url" (blur)="url.invalid && update(false)" type="text" class="form-control" name="url"
         [(ngModel)]="urls" #url="ngModel">
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.required && url.touched">
    URL is required
  </span>
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.pattern && url.touched">
    URL is Invalid
  </span>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, It still fire when url is wrong I have tried both

 (blur)="!url.errors?.pattern && update(false)"

Comment: Try using url. Invalid

Comment: Thanks for reponse. How can I check url.invalid on .ts file

Comment: You can use ViewChild to get the ref of the input element or you can pass the template ref varaible to update method like update(url)